# Why when I create a new activity, "setContentView" not recognize my layout?

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I just created a new activity (project-> new-> android activity) and I get an error where the R file, which does not recognize the layout created by the activity. I use **Ubuntu 13.10 (64 bits)**

```
public class OrderKaraokeActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_karaoke);
    }
}
```

activity_order_karaoke:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".OrderKaraokeActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Console:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
activity_order_karaoke cannot be resolved or is not a field OrderKaraokeActivity.java   /src/com/example/adicionalesprueba  line 18 Java Problem
```

Import:

[image]

Console problem:

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the name of the layout file?

Comment: Is your layout file properly named and placed in `res/layout`?

Comment: What does the error specifically mention? Perhaps your generated R file did not get built

Comment: I hope it ends with .xml

Comment: Are you importing the correct Resource class <your_package_name>.R, and not android.R?

Comment: if you are using eclipse everything should be placed in the right directory, but make sure you have no errors in the code. You can try to add a new string variable to make sure it rebuilds the R

Comment: Perhaps show us what imports you have included for this activity

Comment: @Rperryng R class is import, but I can't put in this post D:

Comment: What do you mean? Just a simple copy and paste of your import statements at the top of your activity would help!

Comment: @Rperryng error 139, That is what happen D:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

remove the following

```
import com.twable.R;
import com.twable.R.layout;
import com.twable.R.menu;
```

and include `import com.example.adicionalesprueba.R`

**----**

Check your package explorer (the left pane of eclipse), open the `gen` folder of your project, open the package of your project, You should see a `R.java` file.  If you do not, you're R file is not being generated.  Try to clean your project, `Project --> Clean`.  If the file is still not there, then you're `R` file is not being built.  This can happen for many reasons.  A very common one is that one of your XML files is not properly structured

[image]

Comment: `The import com.example.adicionalesprueba.R cannot be resolved` and `R cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: strange.  Remove all the import statements I mentioned in the comment, hit `CTRL + SHIFT + O`, you should see a suggestion that matches your package.

Comment: Doen't work, the problem is for layout... R class doen't reconize the layout... it's for error 139 on ubuntu =/ I don't know how fix it

Comment: R.java exist in com.twable packege

Comment: Check your manifest file, the `package` name there should be the one determining what the `R` file is called...

Comment: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.twable"
`

Comment: Well.  I'm honestly stumped.  The only other thing I can think of is that your new Activity class is in the wrong project.  Either that or your eclipse build settings are under some voodoo magic

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports.  Remove **import android.R** if it's generated there.